# How to subtract in mongodb php

Tags: php, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
 $getdataPipeline = array(
            array(
                '$match' => array(
                    'project_id' => array('$in' => $mysql_project_id) // Validating project ID
                ),
                '$match' => array('project_id' => $project_id)
            ),
            array(
                '$group' => array(
                    '_id' => array('pro_id' => '$project_id', 'uid' => '$user_id'),
                    "wh" => array('$subtract' => array(array('$sum' => '$toltal_timein_minutes'), array('$sum' => '$holding_durationin_minutes')))

                ))
        );
```

Running query:

```
  $ValidProjectIdInMongo = $collection->aggregate($getdataPipeline);
```

I'm getting an error like

Uncaught exception 'MongoResultException' with message 'localhost:27017: exception: unknown group operator '$subtract''

Comment: You cannot use `$subtract` in `$group`  stage. It only works with `$project`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [**`$sum`**](https://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/sum/) is the accumulator to be used with **`$group`**, so it must be the top level operator used. Therefore your other operations need to happen "inside" the `$sum`:

```
$getdataPipeline = array(
    array(
        '$match' => array('project_id' => $project_id)
    ),
    array(
        '$group' => array(
            '_id' => array('pro_id' => '$project_id', 'uid' => '$user_id'),
            "wh" => array( 
                '$sum' => array( 
                    '$subtract' => array( 
                        '$toltal_timein_minutes', 
                        '$holding_durationin_minutes'
                    ) 
                ) 
            )
        )
    )
);
```

You can do it here because this is basic subtraction, but more complex operations would generally require a separate `$project` stage after the `$group`.

Also note that yout `$match` pipeline stage is incorrect and will actually be interpretted just as I have re-written above. You perhaps mean in `$in` condition for both the possible values, which is a logical `$or`.

You also have what looks like typing errors in the field names.